# On AS3, how go to a specific frame inside multiple movie clips

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Hello experienced people, I´m working on a dress up game on AS3.
I need to made a button that removes all clothing.

Over the body base, in the main scene, there´s multiple movie clips for each clothing part (ShirtsMC, PantsMC, ShoesMC, etc) inside every MC there´s frames with clothing but there´s always an empty frame [See picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvFD0.png) to simulate a removed item.

Each MC has a different number of items, and my question is how/if can this be done, when press that "RemoveAllClothing" button it commands the multiple movie clips to go at that empty frame in each one of the multiple MC.

I´m not really sure how archive this, any help will be greatly appreciated

-Freefox-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an empty frame (last frame) to all your objects.
When a button is clicked, set your movie clips to last frame (empty).

```
removeAllClothing.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, removeIt);

function removeIt(e:MouseEvent):void
{
   ShirtsMC.gotoAndStop(ShirtsMC.totalFrames);
   PantsMC.gotoAndStop(PantsMC.totalFrames);
   ShoesMC.gotoAndStop(ShoesMC.totalFrames);
}
```

Comment: After some tweaking that work great for my project needs, thanks!